# Is it better to have PHP or MySQL do the heavy lifting?

Tags: php, mysql, search, filter

I spent forever building this custom search function for my site in PHP, where it incrementally builds the MySQL query based on what options and input the end user provides. It works perfectly on my local server, but when I uploaded it to the production site, it runs SUPER slow. I'm relatively new to programming with PHP and MySQL, and so I'm curious in general and for future projects:

When running a search query, is it better to have a complex, exact MySQL query that filters the data and returns the results for PHP to display, or run a simple MySQL query and get a bunch of data from the database and have PHP filter the data and then display the results?

Comment: Filtering in the db as much as possible makes sense in most cases - no point in sending over multi-gigs of data from a huge table, only to have PHP throw out all but a single byte from one field in one record. But, YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

It's a balancing act. Here's my suggestions:

- Use [FULLTEXT](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2003/06/26/fulltext.html) to make string searches faster.
- Order your fields in your WHERE clauses so that indexed columns first, then numerics, then dates, then text fields. This will cut your load by filtering the expensive columns after the cheap ones, reducing the amount of work the database has to do.
- Avoid ORDER when dealing with large data sets, and offload this processing to your PHP code, because it'll save MySQL from ordering the data at each point in the query.
- Index the most commonly used or expensive-to-search fields.
- Don't use a large number of JOINs when you could easily perform two or more queries. A query with 10 or 20 JOINs on some large tables can completely kill your database.
- UNION is useful to perform a few SELECT queries at once on the same table, instead of doing complex logic with OR.

In general, optimal queries should be sufficient. There are some corner cases where doing the work in PHP is useful, but the database should be fast enough for 99% of cases.

Answer (score 1):

if the database is accessed by many web servers probably it will not be a great idea to do make to MySQL server to do lot of processing. secondly, if you use query that produce a big amount of data, that will take your data to transport to web server a long time and you will have to do lot more processing in php.

on the other hand, MySQL use lot of optimization, so that it gets the data efficiently.

so it all depends on what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

I think you can combine it for best results. First and foremost, run a query off of exact matches or really close matches. Basically, if someone searches for the exact name of a page, you want to just return that (= instead of LIKE). Then, maybe if they got the first part right (LIKE 'words%'). Then finally, build a more complex one with MySQL doing the heavy lifting. This ensures the fastest return when the user provides the best data.

Answer (score 0):

There are several variables that come into play when optimizing a web application. Based on what you stated, allowing a user to select several options in order to 'build a query' leads me to believe you may be doing some MySQL ops that are costly. You want to stay away from ORs and if you need to do any ORDER BY you can do it at the application layer by just populated an array of results then sorting the array.

You may also want to consider adding a cache layer that sits above the MySQL layer so you don't have to hit the database every time.

As Kerrek mentioned in his comment you can profile your application to see where the bottlenecks lie, check out XDebug (http://xdebug.org/) and KCacheGrind (http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html)

Just a few ideas to get you started.